# Tizen location of virtual root

Tags: tizen, samsung-galaxy-gear

i'm trying to extract data from samsung S3 frontier tizen app's to run some analysis on the collected data. Tizen offers 2 types of storage, SQLite and in files. I know that each app posses a unique virtual root location, but i don't know where it's located. Also is the SQLite data in the same file?

Answer (score 0):

The base directory of each application package is in general `/opt/usr/home/owner/apps_rw/[pkg_name]` and as far as I understand this is what you mean by *virtual root*.

You can programatically get the data directory of your app by using [`app_get_data_path()`](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=/dev-guide/4.0.0/org.tizen.native.mobile.apireference/group__CAPI__APP__COMMON__MODULE.html#ga284ac2d7468a681d41351c0625cef4e3) in `<app_common.h>`, which will return a string `/opt/usr/home/owner/apps_rw/[pkg_name]/data` (don't forget to free the string after the use). For more information, please find the guide at [File System Directory Hierarchy](https://developer.tizen.org/development/training/native-application/understanding-tizen-programming/file-system-directory-hierarchy).

The above guide will also show you how to get an access to shared media directories using *Storage* APIs. [This](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/native-application/data-storage-and-management/sqlite-database-engine) guide will show you how to store sqlite database file in the storage directory (`STORAGE_DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS`), or you can also store the database file in the private app data directory returned by [`app_get_data_path()`](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=/dev-guide/4.0.0/org.tizen.native.mobile.apireference/group__CAPI__APP__COMMON__MODULE.html#ga284ac2d7468a681d41351c0625cef4e3).